# Excel VBA - Fill known details based on USER ID

Tags: vba, excel, autocomplete

On one sheet, #IDs, i have a list of registered users with different information on each column.

For example:
**#user_id, #phone_number, #address** ... (Each information is on different column). I take this information from an ActiveX Form when users are registering.

On a different sheet, i want people to enter their user_id ONLY, and based on the information on the #IDs sheet, auto-complete the other information (phone, address...). If not registered (=does not exists at the #IDs sheet, give nothing).

I would love to have some help on this small project.

Many many thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just use the `VLOOKUP` Excel function?  (Wrapped in an `IFERROR` to display the blank value if the lookup value doesn't exist.)

Comment: Yes i have looked into that function, but i did not manage to make it work / copy all information to correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is on Sheet1 and Lookup ID is in A2 on Sheet2, then try this...

On Sheet2

In A2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)),"")
```

and then copy it to right.

**Sheet1:**
[image]

**Sheet2**
[image]

Comment: Awesome!
Exactly what i was looking for.
Many thanks! You have helped me a lot!